# PHP: How to bind complex CollectionType-Object to Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, collections

I've got a Problem to bind a complex nested table-type to PHP.

My oracle types:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY.OT_MY_STATUS AS OBJECT
(
  ID_NK NUMBER,
  STATUS CHAR(1)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY.CT_MY_STATUS
AS TABLE OF OT_MY_STATUS;
```

And now I tried to bind a parameter from this type in PHP 5.5:

```
$coll = oci_new_collection($conn, "CT_MY_STATUS", "MY");

//SampleData    
$data = new array();

$oneentry = new object();
$oneentry->ID_NK = 12345;
$oneentry->STATUS = "1";
$data[] = $oneentry;
//***********

$coll->append($data); //Here it crashes :-(

oci_bind_by_name ( $stmt, ":coll", $coll, -1, OCI_B_NTY);
```

I can't append the object-array to the collection.

```
OCI-Collection::append() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

ase said here: http://php.net/manual/en/oci-collection.append.php

"The value to be added to the collection. Can be a string or a number."